# Is there any software that will show me the model number of my Acer Aspire One Netbook

Tags: drivers

Like a champ, I pulled all of the stickers of my Netbook when it was new, after installing Windows 7 Professional and all of the drivers, then deleting the driver installation packages.

I am now checking out the Windows 8 Release Preview and need to install a few drivers (although not nearly as many as I had to on 7) and I don't know the model number!

I have used Speccy to narrow things down a bit but I would idealy like to find the Acer download page for my exact model so I don't have to spend time trolling the internet for things that might work!

The screenshot from Speccy is below, I haven't had much luck searching Google or Bing but if somebody could point me in the right direction that would help a lot:

[image: speccy]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a command prompt and doing a `wmic baseboard` command gives me the following output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sawblade>wmic baseboard
Caption     ConfigOptions  CreationClassName  Depth  Description  Height  HostingBoard  HotSwappable  InstallDate  Manufacturer           Model  Name        OtherIdentifyingInfo  PartNumber  PoweredOn  Product  Removable  Replaceable  RequirementsDescription  RequiresDaughterBoard  SerialNumber      SKU  SlotLayout  SpecialRequirements  Status  Tag         Version  Weight  Width
Base Board                 Win32_BaseBoard           Base Board           TRUE                                     ASUSTeK Computer INC.         Base Board                                    TRUE       900HD                                                                            EeePC-0123456789                                                Base Board  x.xx
```

So you need to scroll all the way to the right, but it reveals the model number of my netbook which is 900HD.

I'm certain this depends on the manufacturer "filling out" the "DMI" fields properly when they build the BIOS for their machine, hopefully Acer isn't lazy.

Comment: The model number was the same as the motherboards but luckily they had put the serial number in there as well which I was able to type into Acer's website and be directed straight to the driver download page! +1

Answer (score 1):

Most newer laptops you can find this information in the bios, on some you can use F1 at the post screen to pull it up without actually entering the bios.

On my HP I can use Fn+Esc while in Windows to pull up this information, not sure if Acer has a key combo for this or not.

Comment: I couldn't use Fn+Esc but yes this information was all in the BIOS, it's been so long since I have had to look in a BIOS I forgot they even existed! +1